# How can I call a PHP function inside a hardcoded shortcode?

Tags: functions, shortcode

Maybe I'm doing this the long way but I need to make something like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[mu-events months="11" startmonth="today" orderby="time" orderas="ASC" sites="?> <?php get_current_site();?> <?php"]'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[mu-events months="11" startmonth="today" orderby="time" orderas="ASC" sites="11"]'); ?>
```

I guess I simply don't know if a function can be inserted inside a shortcode, but in this case it seems like it just has the incorrect syntax.

Appreciate any pointing in the right direction!
Thanks

**NOTE**
There is a different between CURRENT_SITE and current BLOG_ID, see my note below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in this way.

```
echo do_shortcode('[mu-events months="11" startmonth="today" orderby="time" orderas="ASC" sites="' . get_current_site() . '"]');
```

Comment: Would love to hear if this actually works.

Comment: ya it works!!
BUT
ive had to change get_current_site to get_current_blog_id after much confusion why it was always showing the parent ID.